# If and why is it safer to output JS literals into an HTML tag than JS encode them and set them directly to a JS object?

Tags: xss

From [ASP .NET Core docs about preventing XSS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#protecting-your-application-against-xss):

> Before putting untrusted data into JavaScript place the data in an HTML element whose contents you retrieve at runtime. If this isn't possible, then ensure the data is JavaScript encoded. JavaScript encoding takes dangerous characters for JavaScript and replaces them with their hex, for example < would be encoded as `\u003C`.

Later these docs [continue to claim](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cross-site-scripting?view=aspnetcore-2.2#javascript-encoding-using-razor):

> The safest way to insert values is to place the value in a data attribute of a tag and retrieve it in your JavaScript. (...) You can also call the JavaScript encoder directly

Therefore, it would seem to me that the docs claim that HTML escaping a JS literal, outputting it to an HTML tag, then retrieving this literal from JS is safer than JS escaping this literal in such a way that prevents closing the encompassing `script` tag and then outputting it directly to JS code.

Is that so? If yes then why?

To me it would seem that the first approach achieves precisely the same while being more convenient.